# What performance optimizations can you do to improve Core Data Context Start?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, optimization

I am trying to improve my app start time and Core Data is taking most of the time. On the application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions I usually tell my core data handler to load the model, create the context and then the persistent store. Since right after that app starts I would need to start using the database content.

There is not much code really, the two lines that are taking most of the time are:

```
_managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
[_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]
```

So I want to know if there are any optimizations I can add that would make my Core Data Context Start be faster, so far it seems like there is not much to do since it has to load and parse the Core Data Model and then load the sql file in the persistent store.

Comment: This all shouldn't take much time, the first time yet you fetch objects, that will take time... are you sure these two lines above make your app start slow?

Comment: How much time are these two lines taking!?

Comment: They are taking 1 second!

Comment: That's not normal; I really recommend using Instruments to see what's happening during that 1 second. Also, do you actually have more than one data model? Because if you don't `mergedModelFromBundles` might be *slightly* slower than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup core data on another thread. Ofcourse it will not be faster, but UI is more responsive.

Comment: I actually do that for queries I create my background context on another thread and then merge at the end but the problem when starting the context is that other subsystems will use it immediately so I can't have another thread for that taking his time without blocking the rest

Comment: Make notification when coredata is fully initialized and than UI might change/unlock/whatever. In my app when startup takes less than 2 seconds UI is only locked (touches are ignored), after this timeout activity indicator is shown and user knows that he must wait (you can display additional messages that initialization is running or database migration is in progress).